# Django admin inline to model's related model's related model

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models that have foreign keys to the `User` table.

```
class Device(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

So, is it possible to show an Inline form in the Client's admin that shows the Devices that are related to the Client's User?

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: @user2896976 I don't think the docs describe this case. It writes about the case where one needs an inline "with a model with two or more foreign keys to the same parent model" in the parent model. But I don't need the inline in the parent model...

Comment: Do you want to be able to inline edit the devices or just reference them?

Comment: @user2896976 Thanks for the comment. Maybe just reference them ... does it make a big difference?

Comment: If you want to be able to edit the Devices you'll need to create a modelform for them. I'm looking to see if there's a way to just inject some view code into the admin page. The django docs do say that if you want to do work that's outside of the norm then you will need to write your own view, though.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with inlines. Django inlines work only for parent child relations, and in your case there is no such relation. The solution would be to add foreign key in Devices to point to Client, but not sure if it will work for you.